# Android Camera Preview Stretched

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, preview, aspect-ratio

I've been working on making my custom camera activity on Android, but when rotating the camera, the aspect ratio of the surface view gets messed up.

In my oncreate for the activity, I set the framelayout which holds the surface view that displays the camera's parameters.

```
//FrameLayout that will hold the camera preview
        FrameLayout previewHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);

        //Setting camera's preview size to the best preview size
        Size optimalSize = null;
        camera = getCameraInstance();
        double aspectRatio = 0;
        if(camera != null){
            //Setting the camera's aspect ratio
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            optimalSize = CameraPreview.getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
            aspectRatio = (float)optimalSize.width/optimalSize.height;
        }

        if(optimalSize!= null){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*aspectRatio));
            previewHolder.setLayoutParams(params);
            LayoutParams surfaceParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*aspectRatio));
            cameraPreview.setLayoutParams(surfaceParams);

        }

        cameraPreview.setCamera(camera);

        //Adding the preview to the holder
        previewHolder.addView(cameraPreview);
```

Then, in the Surface view I set the camera's parameters to be displayed

```
public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mCamera == camera) { return; }

        mCamera = camera;

        if (mCamera != null) {
            requestLayout();

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if(mCamera != null){
                //Setting the camera's aspect ratio
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);

                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            }

            /*
              Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must 
              be started before you can take a picture.
              */
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    }
```

[image]

You can see that the LEGO man grows taller and skinnier when the phone is rotated:

[image]

**How can I ensure that the aspect ratio for my camera view is correct?**

Comment: @scientific can u pls help me where should i write the given method i m also facing same issue ?

Comment: I seemed to get a similar problem, but what fixed it was calling the following: mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90) in the surfaceCreated() method of my SurfaceView for the camera

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I'm using this method -> based on API Demos to get my Preview Size:

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
```

As you can see you have to input width and height of your screen. This method will calculate screen ratio based on those values and then from the list of supportedPreviewSizes it will choose the best for you from avaliable ones. Get your supportedPreviewSize list in place where Camera object isn't null by using

```
mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

And then on in onMeasure you can get your optimal previewSize like that:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
           mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }
```

And then (in my code in surfaceChanged method, like I said I'm using API Demos structure of CameraActivity code, you can generate it in Eclipse):

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

And one hint for you, because I did almost the same app like you. Good practice for Camera Activity is to hide StatusBar. Applications like Instagram are doing it. It reduces your screen height value and change your ratio value. It is possible to get strange Preview Sizes on some devices (your SurfaceView will be cut a little)

---

And to answer your question, how to check if your preview ratio is correct? Then get height and width of parameters that you set in:

```
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

your set ratio is equal to height/width. If you want camera to look good on your screen then height/width ratio of parameters that you set to camera must be the same as height(minus status bar)/width ratio of your screen.

Comment: Just one question : I see your are using 2 different computed ratio : **double targetRatio=(double)h / w** and **double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height**. The first one is the height divided by the width and the other is the opposite, the width divided by the height. Should they not be the same computation ?

Comment: It doesn't matter because list of sizes takes into consideration every  possibility for example: you will find something like 480x680, but sooner or later there will be 680x480 (for landscape), so you just have to go over that list and find one that matches your needs. You will find it sooner or later.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want your pictures to be this size as well (as they probably should be), you have set the picture size with `parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height)`.

Comment: @F1sher, i always get null pointer exception parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
Can't find any solution.

Comment: @F1sher If I am using fullscreen to preview then optimal preview size always will be screen resolution.. Please correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: @phyzalis I agree with you. In fact, I had to make that correction for the code to work as expected.

Comment: I am using activity, and there is no onMeasure method in it. :( I know that i need a separate class which extends SurfaceView but then i get NullPointerException..

Comment: Hello I'm dealing with the same problem , and your answer is quite clear . but my surface view is inside a Framelayout so I have created a customised view which extends FrmaLayout . I have done this to Override the onMeasure() method . But inside this method you wrote a methode resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec) . Can you please show me this method's functionality . @F1sher

Comment: I haven't touched that code in 2 years or even more but if that helps you:
https://gist.github.com/FisherHUB/ca209e4cb740b65b4ee6 and resolveSize is not my method, it's part of ViewGroup. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Comment: Did you just copy the code from here?
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/Gettheoptimalpreviewsizeforthegivenscreensize.htm

Comment: Hello, as I have written, I generated this code in Eclipse from provided Android solutions called API demos, few years ago.

Comment: I am getting white screen when I follow your code. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: @F1sher I am getting white screen when I followed your code. In `onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)` method I always get width = 0 and height = 0;

Comment: This solution doesn't fix it for me. However, just replacing the target high with `int targetHeight = (int) ((double) h * targetRatio);` works for me!!!

Comment: class `Camera.Size` is deprecated.

Comment: This camera rotation will break !
Use the code on the android docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)

Comment: i need solution in kotlin if you have please send me

Answer (score 156):

F1Sher's solution is nice but sometimes doesn't work. Particularly, when your surfaceView doesn't cover whole screen. In this case you need to override onMeasure() method.
I have copied my code here for your reference.

Since I measured surfaceView based on width then I have little bit white gap at the end of my screen that I filled it by design. You are able to fix this issue if you keep height and increase width by multiply it to ratio. However, it will squish surfaceView slightly.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mCamera = camera;

        // supported preview sizes
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for(Camera.Size str: mSupportedPreviewSizes)
                Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. surfaceChanged will take care of stuff
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        if (mPreviewSize!=null) {
            float ratio;
            if(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
                ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
            else
                ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

            // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
            setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
  //        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer, it handles the case when the camera's preview is not covering the whole screen. +1 .

Comment: when I inflate in my activity application was closed <com.app.camera.CameraPreview
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

Comment: You need to make some modifications though but I accept this as a solution. Up-voted.

Comment: hi @Hesam , can u explain more and show me about your Activity class , how you use this code .

Comment: Hi @adnan9011 , this tutorial might be helpful probably. https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment

Comment: @Hesam Kamalan , i write activity but not showing any thing in surfaceview . one thing is wrong

Comment: the height and width needed to be switched in `getOptimalPreviewSize` for this to work for me. is this because the display orientation was set to 90? Otherwise, the ratio calculations weren't even close (target was 1.7 and camera ratios were less than 1)

Comment: camera showing blank(Black) screen. mPreview = new CameraPreviewNew(getActivity(), mCamera);
        topLayout.addView(mPreview);   same code copy paste.

Comment: camera move blink blur camera quality few seconds.Any solution

Comment: @Hesam  I am getting white screen when I followed your code. In onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) method I always get width = 0 and height = 0;

Comment: I didn't thought that adjusting the measured dimensions would fix it, works like a charm. In my case I took the preview parameters from the camera because I had it configured already.

Comment: mContext is not necessary in this case as the same value will be provided by getContext()

Answer (score 24):

NOTE: MY SOLUTION IS A CONTINUATION OF HESAM'S SOLUTION: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22758359/1718734

What I address: Hesam's said there is a little white space that may appear on some phones, like this:

[image: NOTE: Although the aspect ratio is correct, the camera does not fill in the whole screen.]

Hesam suggested a second solution, but that squishes the preview. And on some devices, it heavily distorts.

So how do we fix this problem. It is simple...by multiplying the aspect ratios till it fills in the screen. I have noticed, several popular apps such as Snapchat, WhatsApp, etc works the same way.

All you have to do is add this to the onMeasure method:

```
float camHeight = (int) (width * ratio);
    float newCamHeight;
    float newHeightRatio;

    if (camHeight < height) {
        newHeightRatio = (float) height / (float) mPreviewSize.height;
        newCamHeight = (newHeightRatio * camHeight);
        Log.e(TAG, camHeight + " " + height + " " + mPreviewSize.height + " " + newHeightRatio + " " + newCamHeight);
        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * newHeightRatio), (int) newCamHeight);
        Log.e(TAG, mPreviewSize.width + " | " + mPreviewSize.height + " | ratio - " + ratio + " | H_ratio - " + newHeightRatio + " | A_width - " + (width * newHeightRatio) + " | A_height - " + newCamHeight);
    } else {
        newCamHeight = camHeight;
        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) newCamHeight);
        Log.e(TAG, mPreviewSize.width + " | " + mPreviewSize.height + " | ratio - " + ratio + " | A_width - " + (width) + " | A_height - " + newCamHeight);
    }
```

This will calculate the screen height and gets the ratio of the screen height and the mPreviewSize height. Then it multiplies the camera's width and height by the new height ratio and the set the measured dimension accordingly.

[image]

And the next thing you know, you end up with this :D

[image]

This also works well with he front camera. I believe this is the best way to go about this. Now the only thing left for my app is to save the preview itself upon clicking on "Capture." But ya, this is it.

Comment: This works very good!! but it does not work properly in Landscape :/

Comment: your code solved my 2 months empty black space problem :)

Comment: It works, but in my case.. I have actionbar on the top so the white bar was smaller, however after adding your code my camera look zoomed in 40-50%. When switching to the front facing camera I basically cannot see my face looking straight (just a bit of hair), because of that high zoom.

Comment: @Yoosuf  I am getting white screen when I followed your code. In `onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)` method I always get width = 0 and height = 0;

Answer (score 11):

OK, so I think **there is no sufficient answer** for general camera preview stretching problem. Or at least I didn't find one. My app also suffered this stretching syndrome and it took me a while to puzzle together a solution from all the user answers on this portal and internet.

I tried @Hesam's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22758359/3422034) but it didn't work and left my camera preview majorly distorted.

First I show the code of my solution (the important parts of the code) and then I explain why I took those steps. There is room for performance modifications.

**Main activity xml layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Camera Preview:**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder prHolder;
private Camera prCamera;
public List<Camera.Size> prSupportedPreviewSizes;
private Camera.Size prPreviewSize;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public YoCameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    prCamera = camera;

    prSupportedPreviewSizes = prCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    prHolder = getHolder();
    prHolder.addCallback(this);
    prHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        prCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        prCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Yologram", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if (prHolder.getSurface() == null){
      return;
    }

    try {
        prCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }

    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = prCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }
        parameters.setPreviewSize(prPreviewSize.width, prPreviewSize.height);

        prCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        prCamera.setPreviewDisplay(prHolder);
        prCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Yologram", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if (prSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        prPreviewSize = 
            getOptimalPreviewSize(prSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }    
}

public Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {

    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    if (sizes == null)
        return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;

        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}
}
```

**Main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

...

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        maCamera = getCameraInstance();

        maLayoutPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        maPreview = new CameraPreview(this, maCamera);

        Point displayDim = getDisplayWH();
        Point layoutPreviewDim = calcCamPrevDimensions(displayDim, 
                maPreview.getOptimalPreviewSize(maPreview.prSupportedPreviewSizes, 
                    displayDim.x, displayDim.y));
        if (layoutPreviewDim != null) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutPreviewParams = 
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) maLayoutPreview.getLayoutParams();
            layoutPreviewParams.width = layoutPreviewDim.x;
            layoutPreviewParams.height = layoutPreviewDim.y;
            layoutPreviewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            maLayoutPreview.setLayoutParams(layoutPreviewParams);
        }
        maLayoutPreview.addView(maPreview);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Point getDisplayWH() {

    Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point displayWH = new Point();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        display.getSize(displayWH);
        return displayWH;
    }
    displayWH.set(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
    return displayWH;
}

private Point calcCamPrevDimensions(Point disDim, Camera.Size camDim) {

    Point displayDim = disDim;
    Camera.Size cameraDim = camDim;

    double widthRatio = (double) displayDim.x / cameraDim.width;
    double heightRatio = (double) displayDim.y / cameraDim.height;

    // use ">" to zoom preview full screen
    if (widthRatio < heightRatio) {
        Point calcDimensions = new Point();
        calcDimensions.x = displayDim.x;
        calcDimensions.y = (displayDim.x * cameraDim.height) / cameraDim.width;
        return calcDimensions;
    }
    // use "<" to zoom preview full screen
    if (widthRatio > heightRatio) { 
        Point calcDimensions = new Point();
        calcDimensions.x = (displayDim.y * cameraDim.width) / cameraDim.height;
        calcDimensions.y = displayDim.y;
        return calcDimensions;
    }
    return null;
}   
}
```

**My commentary:**

The point of all this is, that although you calculate the **optimal camera size** in `getOptimalPreviewSize()` you only pick the **closest ratio** to fit your screen. So unless the ratio is exactly **the same** the preview will stretch.

Why will it stretch? Because your FrameLayout camera preview is set in **layout.xml** to **match_parent** in width and height. So that is why the preview will stretch to full screen.

What needs to be done is to **set camera preview layout** width and height to match the chosen **camera size ratio**, so the preview keeps its aspect ratio and won't distort.

I tried to use the `CameraPreview` class to do all the calculations and layout changes, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406953/3422034), but `SurfaceView` doesn't recognize `getChildCount ()` or `getChildAt (int index)`. I think, I got it working eventually with a reference to `maLayoutPreview`, but it was misbehaving and applied the set ratio to my whole app and it did so after first picture was taken. So I let it go and moved the layout modifications to the `MainActivity`.

In `CameraPreview` I changed `prSupportedPreviewSizes` and `getOptimalPreviewSize()` to **public** so I can use it in `MainActivity`. Then I needed the **display dimensions** (minus the navigation/status bar if there is one) and chosen optimal **camera size**. I tried to get the RelativeLayout (or FrameLayout) size instead of display size, but it was returning zero value. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548045/3422034) didn't work for me. The layout got it's value after `onWindowFocusChanged` (checked in the log).

So I have my methods for calculating the layout dimensions to match the aspect ratio of chosen camera size. Now you just need to set `LayoutParams` of your camera preview layout. Change the width, height and center it in parent.

There are two choices how to calculate the preview dimensions. Either you want it to fit the screen with **black bars** (if windowBackground is set to null) on the sides or top/bottom. Or you want the preview **zoomed to full screen**. I left comment with more information in `calcCamPrevDimensions()`.

Answer (score 6):

Hi the getOptimalPreview() that is here didn't worked for me so I want to share my version:

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {

    if (sizes==null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double ratio = (double)h/w;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double newDiff;
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        newDiff = Math.abs((double)size.width/size.height - ratio);
        if (newDiff < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = newDiff;
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

Comment: it converts into a square camera, Given input is (1920x1080) after optimizing width and height it gave (1088x1088), My testing device is Samsung S6. May I know what is the reason. please share if u have any idea regarding this issue.

Comment: reason maybe, you are passing the same width and height.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make this thread more complete i am adding my version of answer:

What i wanted to achieve: 
The surface view shouldn't be stretched, and it should cover the whole screen, Moreover, there was only a landscape mode in my app.

Solution:

The solution is an extremely small extension to F1sher's solution:

=> First step is to integrate F1sher's solution.

=> Now, there might arise a scenario in F1sher's solution when the surface view doesn't covers the whole screen, The solution is to make the surface view greater than the screen dimensions so that it covers the whole screen, for that:

```
    size = getOptimalPreviewSize(mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes(), screenWidth, screenHeight);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);


    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);      

    double screenRatio = (double) screenHeight / screenWidth;
    double previewRatio = (double) size.height / size.width;

    if (previewRatio > screenRatio)     /*if preview ratio is greater than screen ratio then we will have to recalculate the surface height while keeping the surface width equal to the screen width*/
    {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, (int) (screenWidth * previewRatio));
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        flPreview.setLayoutParams(params1);

        flPreview.setClipChildren(false);

        LayoutParams surfaceParams = new LayoutParams(screenWidth, (int) (screenWidth * previewRatio));
        surfaceParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mPreview.setLayoutParams(surfaceParams);        
    }
    else     /*if preview ratio is smaller than screen ratio then we will have to recalculate the surface width while keeping the surface height equal to the screen height*/
    {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) ((double) screenHeight / previewRatio), screenHeight);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        flPreview.setLayoutParams(params1);
        flPreview.setClipChildren(false);

        LayoutParams surfaceParams = new LayoutParams((int) ((double) screenHeight / previewRatio), screenHeight);
        surfaceParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mPreview.setLayoutParams(surfaceParams);

    }       

    flPreview.addView(mPreview); 

  /*  The TopMost layout used is the RelativeLayout, flPreview is the FrameLayout in which Surface View is added, mPreview is an instance of a class which extends SurfaceView  */
```

Answer (score 2):

@Hesam 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22758359/10989990) is correct, `CameraPreview` will work in all portrait devices, but if the device is in landscape mode or in multi-window mode, this code is working perfect, just replace `onMeasure()`

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    int rotation = ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    if ((Surface.ROTATION_0 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation)) {//portrait
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, height, width);
    } else
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);//landscape

    if (mPreviewSize == null) return;
    float ratio;
    if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width) {
        ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
    } else ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && ((Activity) mContext).isInMultiWindowMode()) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ||
                !(Surface.ROTATION_0 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation)) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width / ratio));
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension((int) (height / ratio), height);
        }
    } else {
        if ((Surface.ROTATION_0 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation)) {
            Log.e("---", "onMeasure: " + height + " - " + width * ratio);
            //2264 - 2400.0 pix c -- yes
            //2240 - 2560.0 samsung -- yes
            //1582 - 1440.0 pix 2 -- no
            //1864 - 2048.0 sam tab -- yes
            //848 - 789.4737 iball -- no
            //1640 - 1600.0 nexus 7 -- no
            //1093 - 1066.6667 lenovo -- no
            //if width * ratio is > height, need to minus toolbar height
           if ((width * ratio) < height)
                setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
            else
                setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio) - toolbarHeight);
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension((int) (height * ratio), height);
        }
    }
    requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what's the problem - it is with **orientation** changes. If you change camera orientation to 90 or 270 degrees than you need to **swap width and height** of supported sizes and all will be ok.

Also surface view should lie in a frame layout and have center gravity.

Here is example on C# (Xamarin):

```
public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, Android.Graphics.Format format, int width, int height)
{
    _camera.StopPreview();

    // find best supported preview size

    var parameters = _camera.GetParameters();
    var supportedSizes = parameters.SupportedPreviewSizes;
    var bestPreviewSize = supportedSizes
        .Select(x => new { Width = x.Height, Height = x.Width, Original = x }) // HACK swap height and width because of changed orientation to 90 degrees
        .OrderBy(x => Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x.Width - width), 3) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x.Height - height), 2))
        .First();

    if (height == bestPreviewSize.Height && width == bestPreviewSize.Width)
    {
        // start preview if best supported preview size equals current surface view size

        parameters.SetPreviewSize(bestPreviewSize.Original.Width, bestPreviewSize.Original.Height);
        _camera.SetParameters(parameters);
        _camera.StartPreview();
    }
    else
    {
        // if not than change surface view size to best supported (SurfaceChanged will be called once again)

        var layoutParameters = _surfaceView.LayoutParameters;
        layoutParameters.Width = bestPreviewSize.Width;
        layoutParameters.Height = bestPreviewSize.Height;
        _surfaceView.LayoutParameters = layoutParameters;
    }
}
```

Pay attention that camera parameters should be set as original size (not swapped), and surface view size should be swapped.

Answer (score 1):

i tried all the solution above but none of them works for me. finaly i solved it myself, and find actually it's quite easy. there are two points you need to be careful.

```
parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y);
```

this previewSize must be one of the camera supported resolution, which can be get as below:

```
List<Camera.Size> rawSupportedSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

usually one of the rawSupportedSize equals to the device resolution.

Second, place your SurfaceView in a FrameLayout and set the surface layout height and width in surfaceChanged method as above

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = cameraResolution.x;
layoutParams.width = cameraResolution.y;
```

Ok, things done, hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Very important point here to understand , the SurfaceView size must be the same as the camera parameters size , it means they have the same aspect ratio then the Stretch effect will go off .

You have to get the correct supported camera preview size using params.getSupportedPreviewSizes() choose one of them and then change your SurfaceView and its holders to this size.

Answer (score 0):

My requirements are the camera preview need to be fullscreen and keep the aspect ratio.
Hesam and Yoosuf's solution was great but I do see a high zoom problem for some reason.

The idea is the same, have the preview container center in parent and increase the width or height depend on the aspect ratios until it can cover the entire screen.

One thing to note is the preview size is in landscape because we set the display orientation.

> camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

The container that we will add the SurfaceView view to:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Add the preview to it's container with center in parent in your activity.

```
this.cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
cameraPreviewContainer.removeAllViews();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
cameraPreviewContainer.addView(cameraPreview, 0, params);
```

Inside the CameraPreview class:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    stopPreview();

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    try {
        Camera.Size nativePictureSize = CameraUtils.getNativeCameraPictureSize(camera);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(nativePictureSize.width, nativePictureSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

    if (supportedPreviewSizes != null && optimalSize == null) {
        optimalSize = CameraUtils.getOptimalSize(supportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        Log.i(TAG, "optimal size: " + optimalSize.width + "w, " + optimalSize.height + "h");
    }

    float previewRatio =  (float) optimalSize.height / (float) optimalSize.width;
    // previewRatio is height/width because camera preview size are in landscape.
    float measuredSizeRatio = (float) width / (float) height;

    if (previewRatio >= measuredSizeRatio) {
        measuredHeight = height;
        measuredWidth = (int) ((float)height * previewRatio);
    } else {
        measuredWidth = width;
        measuredHeight = (int) ((float)width / previewRatio);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Preview size: " + width + "w, " + height + "h");
    Log.i(TAG, "Preview size calculated: " + measuredWidth + "w, " + measuredHeight + "h");

    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a lil late for you but hopefully not for everybody.

What you can use to ensure a specific ration is the attribute:

```
layout_constraintDimensionRatio="ration_a:ratio_b"
```

It solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is an update to the @Hesam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22758359/10989990), which addresses the following:

1. Final view is distorted in few screens
2. Preview is laid at the very top of screen, not centralized, which looks very weird.

---

You just have to update the onMeasure like this, everything else remains the same.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

    //centralize preview
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, (int) height);
    surfaceParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    this.setLayoutParams(surfaceParams);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }

    if (mPreviewSize != null) {
        float ratio;
        if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        else
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));


        //fix distortion, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30634009/6688493
        float camHeight = (int) (width * ratio);
        float newCamHeight;
        float newHeightRatio;

        if (camHeight < height) {
            newHeightRatio = (float) height / (float) mPreviewSize.height;
            newCamHeight = (newHeightRatio * camHeight);
            Log.e(TAG, camHeight + " " + height + " " + mPreviewSize.height + " " + newHeightRatio + " " + newCamHeight);
            setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * newHeightRatio), (int) newCamHeight);
            Log.e(TAG, mPreviewSize.width + " | " + mPreviewSize.height + " | ratio - " + ratio + " | H_ratio - " + newHeightRatio + " | A_width - " + (width * newHeightRatio) + " | A_height - " + newCamHeight);
        } else {
            newCamHeight = camHeight;
            setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) newCamHeight);
            Log.e(TAG, mPreviewSize.width + " | " + mPreviewSize.height + " | ratio - " + ratio + " | A_width - " + (width) + " | A_height - " + newCamHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must set cameraView.getLayoutParams().height and cameraView.getLayoutParams().width according to the aspect ratio you want.

Comment: is this different than setting my camera view's parameter this way (which I'm currently doing):

                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

Answer (score -2):

I gave up the calculations and simply get the size of the view where I want the camera preview displayed and set the camera's preview size the same (just flipped width/height due to rotation) in my custom SurfaceView implementation:

```
@Override // CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { 
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
        final Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        // viewParams is from the view where the preview is displayed
        params.setPreviewSize(viewParams.height, viewParams.width);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        requestLayout();
        camera.setParameters(params);
    }
    // I do not enable rotation, so this can otherwise stay as is
}
```

Comment: The Android doc says: _When setting preview size, you must use values from getSupportedPreviewSizes(). Do not set arbitrary values in the setPreviewSize() method._