# How to get programmatically width and height of Relative - Linear layout in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I required runtime dimensions of Relative/Linear Layout.

**activity_home.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeActivity.java:

```
private int width, height;

RelativeLayout rlParent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlParent);

w = rlParent.getWidth();
h = rlParent.getHeight();

Log.i("Width-Height", width+"-"+height);
```

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I have implemented by this way:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = linearLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```

This example is for **Linear** layout, for **Relative** layout follow same process.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: do you able to get the width?

Comment: @N.Droid, Yes. both.

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    updateSizeInfo();
}

private void updateSizeInfo() {
    RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
    w = rlayout.getWidth();
    h = rlayout.getHeight();
    Log.v("W-H", w+"-"+h);
}
```

Comment: Accept and close the question. Thanks

Comment: i can not accept answer till 7 min from your answer time, just wait for 2 min :)

Answer (score 5):

You can attach a OnGlobalLayoutListener to ViewTreeObserver of the relative layout which will get called when the view is attached to the window and it's actual height is assigned to it.

```
final RelativeLayout rl_cards_details_card_area = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_cards_details_card_area);
        rl_cards_details_card_area.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int w = rl_cards_details_card_area.getWidth();
                        int h = rl_cards_details_card_area.getHeight();
                        Log.v("W-H", w + "-" + h);
                        rl_cards_details_card_area.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidResizeView extends Activity {

    TextView textMyTextView;
    Button myButton;

    RelativeLayout rlayout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hightk);

        rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);

        textMyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                updateSizeInfo();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        updateSizeInfo();
    }

    private void updateSizeInfo() {

        textMyTextView.setText(String.valueOf("Width: "
                + rlayout.getWidth() + "height ::" + rlayout.getHeight()));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

we may not get correct height and wight of a view or layout as soon the activity is just created since the layout is not inflated completly

so

1.either you can let a runnable method triggered after some secs which in turn call a function that gets the width and height properties.

2.we can use view tree obsever

```
 l = (RelativeLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.rl_cards_details_card_area);
ViewTreeObserver observer = l.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ActivityClassName.this.getProperties();
        l.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                this);
    }
});
void getProperties() {
    int a= l.getHeight();
        int b = l.getWidth();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity,""+a+" "+b,1000).show();
    }
```

Comment: Why you have answered the same which @vipul had already posted. The place is not supposed to copy answers, instead you can upvote if your answer is similar.

Comment: sorry the answer was being typed by me  at same time and didn't copy it - thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin**: You can use AndroidX's doOnLayout extension function to get height or width of a layout

```
view.doOnLayout {
  Timber.d("View's Height: ${view.height}")
}
```

> Performs the given action when this view is laid out. If the view has
>   been laid out and it has not requested a layout, the action will be
>   performed straight away, otherwise the action will be performed after
>   the view is next laid out.
>
> The action will only be invoked once on the next layout and then
>   removed. [For more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).doOnLayout(kotlin.Function1))