# Camera preview stretched when trying to set in SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, surfaceview, screen-resolution

I am trying to set Camera preview in SurfaceView
When I set Camera in Surface it looks like stretched preview.
How can I solve this?[image]

```
`public class CamActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`
`{`
`Camera camera;`
`SurfaceView surface;`
`SurfaceHolder mholder;`
`Button capture;`
`Bitmap bitmap;`
`public  String  path = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Cam";`
@Override
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) `
`{`
 `   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
  `  setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam);`
   ` surface=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);`
   ` if(mholder==null)`
    `   mholder=surface.getHolder();`
   ` mholder.addCallback(this);`
    `mholder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);`

    `capture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.camera_capture);`
    `File mFolder = new File(path);`
    `if (!mFolder.exists()) {`
     `   mFolder.mkdir();`
    `}`
    `capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`

    `   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`
    `   @Override`
    `   public void onClick(View v) {`
    `        camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback()` 
    `        {`

                @Override
    `           public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)`
    `           {`

    `               Random generator = new Random();`
    `               int n = 10000;`
    `               n = generator.nextInt(n);`
    `               String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";`
    `               File pictureFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(`
    `                         Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/", fname);`
    `                try {`
    `                       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);`
    `                       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90, fos);`
    `                       fos.flush();`
    `                       fos.close();`
    `                   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {`
                            `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
    `                   } catch (IOException e) {`
                            `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
    `                   }`

    `           }`
    `       });`
    `   }`
    `});`
`}`

@Override
`public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) `
`{`
`    camera=Camera.open();`
`    try` 
`    {`
`        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);`
`        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
`    } `
`    catch (IOException exception)` 
`    {`
`         camera.release();`
`         camera = null;`
`    }`
`}`

@Override
`public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) `
`{`
 `   camera.startPreview();`
  `  camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);`
`}`

@Override
`public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)` 
`{
`   camera.stopPreview();`
`    camera.release();`
`    camera = null;`        
`}`
`}`
```

Comment: can you put your code ?

Comment: Your Surfaceview's size is not the same as the video dimensions. Either decrease the height proportionally to the width or make the width full screen with the camera button as just an overlay on top of it.

Comment: How can i set same size? @Shobhit Puri

Comment: check my code #Moradiya Aksh

Comment: See Grafika for some examples (https://github.com/google/grafika).  It shows using a custom layout (`AspectFrameLayout`) to set the size of a SurfaceView, and accomplishing the same thing with TextureView using the view matrix rather than a layout.

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash please give me answer

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577299/android-camera-preview-stretched

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen to orientation change in the activity and set the proper orientation to the camera.

Add this method to your camera activity:

```
public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity) {

    if(null == mCamera){
        return;
     }

       android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = 
           new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();

       android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

       int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
       int degrees = 0;

       switch (rotation) {
           case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
           case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
           case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
           case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
       }


       if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
           orientation = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
           orientation = (360 - orientation) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
       } else {  // back-facing
           orientation = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
       }

       if(null != mCamera){
           mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(orientation);
       }
    }
```

also add OrientationEventListner

```
    mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(mApplication, 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

            if ((orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) || (mCamera == null)) {
                return;
            }

            Camera.Parameters params                = mCamera.getParameters();               
            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();

            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

            orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

            int rotation = 0;

            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
            }
            else {  
                /*
                 * back-facing camera
                 */
                rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
            }

            params.setRotation(rotation);

            if(null == mCamera) {
                return;
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }

    };
```

Enable orientation listener once the activity starts
        /*
         * start orientation listener 
         */
        if(mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()){
            mOrientationEventListener.enable();
        }

and in the onConfigurationChanged and onResume callback of the activity , make the following call

setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity)

Hope this helps

Regards,
Shrish

EDIT UPDATE:
Please check out this sample code for camera , most of your doubts should get cleared
https://github.com/shrishmv/CameraTest

Comment: How can i get cameraId ?

Comment: please give me answer

Comment: check the github project

Comment: Download and run the sample app from github. It should not give any error. Use it as a reference and modify your code accordingly. Can you tell me what exactly you tried to do ?

Comment: I just want to set camera properly in SurfaceView. And the camera screen that displayed in SurfaceView is not stretched

Comment: Check these things (use my sample app as reference)
1) set the proper preview size and picture size. ie. first query supported size and set appropriate size
2) set the layout params (height and width) of the camera preivew i.e. surfaceview equal to the preview seize set or a size of the same aspect ratio
3) set the orientation properly , whenever the screen rotates or surfaceview changes 
4) If your surfaceview streches beyond the screen/acticity, then  set the layout params of the parent to the desired size and then set the surfaceview layout params.

All this is done in my sample app.

Comment: This really Awesome! Shrish