# How to get full size image from custom front camera with full screen length

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am making an android app which is using the front camera of device and it has to take picture in portrait form also it would want to save picture in the same result as it is showing in the preview but when I take photo and save the bitmap the bitmap seems very awkward as it increases the size in length. It seems that I am doing something wrong which is squeezing the camera picture while saving.

I have searched many links and came to know that for this we have to set the aspect ratio. SO I did not  get it. I want help in my coding because I have about to complete my app and it is working best on samsung grand and S4 but it is not Working good on Lg g3 and .

Here is what I am doing with surfaceview class . I am sharing the only surface view class As I know that there is something wrong here , rest of other classes are easy . 
**CameraPreview.java**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Camera camera;
public static  SurfaceHolder holder;
private Activity activity;


public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Activity activity) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void init(Camera camera,Activity activity) {
    this.camera = camera;
    this.activity = activity;
    initSurfaceHolder();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // needed for < 3.0
private void initSurfaceHolder() {
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    initCamera(holder);
}

private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0); //480h x 720w
        for(int i = 0 ; i<=6;i++){


            Log.v("preview sizes"+previewSizes.get(i));
            Camera.Size previewSizedemo = previewSizes.get(i);
            Log.v("preview size are" +previewSizedemo.width+""+ previewSizedemo.height+"of"+i);
            Camera.Size previewSizedemo1 = previewSizes.get(1);
            Log.v("preview size of 0 is" +previewSizedemo1.width+""+ previewSizedemo1.height);
        }

        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width,previewSize.height);

     parameters.setZoom(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_DISTANCE_OPTIMAL_INDEX);

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        requestLayout();
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error setting camera preview", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder mHolder, int format, int width, int height) {

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0); //480h x 720w

    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width,previewSize.height);


       requestLayout();

    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    Display display = ((WindowManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    } else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    }

    camera.startPreview();





}// end surfaceChanged





@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e("TABACT"+"surfaceDestroyed()");
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    camera.release();
    camera = null;

    this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);


}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

> Keep in Mind I am only using front facing camera only. Please help me in it how can I take full length image from front camera with out getting inverted to any other angle then portrait.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Camera Preview Stretched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577299/android-camera-preview-stretched)

Comment: I have seen this question before But the answer in this is not so much clear and convincing