# Android camera scales aspect ratio on Google Cardboard

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, google-cardboard

I' ve been working on Google Cardboard for some research.

I faced some problem when I was trying to open camera on Google Cardboard. The problem is aspect ratio. When I was looking the camera with Google Cardboard, it looks like more thinner then reality. As you can see the images below...

Normal image:
[image: Normal image]

Cardboard image:
[image: Cardboard image]

And these are the codes.

CardboardOverlayView.java

```
public class CardboardOverlayView extends LinearLayout {
private static final String TAG = CardboardOverlayView.class.getSimpleName();
private final CardboardOverlayEyeView mLeftView;
private final CardboardOverlayEyeView mRightView;
private AlphaAnimation mTextFadeAnimation;

public CardboardOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    mLeftView = new CardboardOverlayEyeView(context, attrs);
    mLeftView.setLayoutParams(params);
    addView(mLeftView);

    mRightView = new CardboardOverlayEyeView(context, attrs);
    mRightView.setLayoutParams(params);
    addView(mRightView);

    // Set some reasonable defaults.
    setDepthOffset(0.016f);
    setColor(Color.rgb(150, 255, 180));
    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mTextFadeAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    mTextFadeAnimation.setDuration(5000);
}

public void show3DToast(String message) {
    setText(message);
    setTextAlpha(1f);
    mTextFadeAnimation.setAnimationListener(new EndAnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            setTextAlpha(0f);
        }
    });
    startAnimation(mTextFadeAnimation);
}

private abstract class EndAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
}

private void setDepthOffset(float offset) {
    mLeftView.setOffset(offset);
    mRightView.setOffset(-offset);
}

private void setText(String text) {
    mLeftView.setText(text);
    mRightView.setText(text);
}

private void setTextAlpha(float alpha) {
    mLeftView.setTextViewAlpha(alpha);
    mRightView.setTextViewAlpha(alpha);
}

private void setColor(int color) {
    mLeftView.setColor(color);
    mRightView.setColor(color);
}

/**
 * A simple view group containing some horizontally centered text underneath a horizontally
 * centered image.
 *
 * This is a helper class for CardboardOverlayView.
 */
private class CardboardOverlayEyeView extends ViewGroup {
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final TextView textView;
    private float offset;

    public CardboardOverlayEyeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        imageView = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  // Preserve aspect ratio.
        addView(imageView);

        textView = new TextView(context, attrs);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14.0f);
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setShadowLayer(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Color.DKGRAY);
        addView(textView);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        imageView.setColorFilter(color);
        textView.setTextColor(color);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public void setTextViewAlpha(float alpha) {
        textView.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    public void setOffset(float offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        // Width and height of this ViewGroup.
        final int width = right - left;
        final int height = bottom - top;

        // The size of the image, given as a fraction of the dimension as a ViewGroup. We multiply
        // both width and heading with this number to compute the image's bounding box. Inside the
        // box, the image is the horizontally and vertically centered.
        final float imageSize = 0.12f;

        // The fraction of this ViewGroup's height by which we shift the image off the ViewGroup's
        // center. Positive values shift downwards, negative values shift upwards.
        final float verticalImageOffset = -0.07f;

        // Vertical position of the text, specified in fractions of this ViewGroup's height.
        final float verticalTextPos = 0.52f;

        // Layout ImageView
        float imageMargin = (1.0f - imageSize) / 2.0f;
        float leftMargin = (int) (width * (imageMargin + offset));
        float topMargin = (int) (height * (imageMargin + verticalImageOffset));
        imageView.layout(
                (int) leftMargin, (int) topMargin,
                (int) (leftMargin + width * imageSize), (int) (topMargin + height * imageSize));

        // Layout TextView
        leftMargin = offset * width;
        topMargin = height * verticalTextPos;
        textView.layout(
                (int) leftMargin, (int) topMargin,
                (int) (leftMargin + width), (int) (topMargin + height * (1.0f - verticalTextPos)));
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends CardboardActivity implements CardboardView.StereoRenderer, OnFrameAvailableListener {

private static final String TAG = "VRCamMtMMainAc";
private static final int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;
private Camera camera;

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 position;" +
                "attribute vec2 inputTextureCoordinate;" +
                "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;" +
                "void main()" +
                "{" +
                "gl_Position = position;" +
                "textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;                            \n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES s_texture;               \n" +
                "void main(void) {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, textureCoordinate );\n" +
                //"  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
                "}";

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, textureVerticesBuffer, vertexBuffer2;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer, buf2;
private int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle, mPositionHandle2;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mTextureCoordHandle;


// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
static float squareVertices[] = { // in counterclockwise order:
        -1.0f, -1.0f,   // 0.left - mid
        1.0f, -1.0f,   // 1. right - mid
        -1.0f, 1.0f,   // 2. left - top
        1.0f, 1.0f,   // 3. right - top

};


private short drawOrder[] = {0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3}; // order to draw vertices
private short drawOrder2[] = {2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1}; // order to draw vertices

static float textureVertices[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom
        1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom
        0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top
        1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top
};

private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

private ByteBuffer indexBuffer;    // Buffer for index-array

private int texture;
private CardboardOverlayView mOverlayView;
private CardboardView cardboardView;
private SurfaceTexture surface;
private float[] mView;
private float[] mCamera;

public void startCamera(int texture) {
    surface = new SurfaceTexture(texture);
    surface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

  // Check what resolutions are supported by your camera
    /*List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

    // Iterate through all available resolutions and choose one.
    // The chosen resolution will be stored in mSize.
    Camera.Size mSize = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Available resolution: " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
        mSize = size;
    }
    params.setPictureSize(5312,2988);*/

    camera.setParameters(params);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "CAM LAUNCH FAILED");
    }

}

static private int createTexture() {
    int[] texture = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return texture[0];
}


private int loadGLShader(int type, String code) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, code);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    // Get the compilation status.
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

    // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error compiling shader: " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
        shader = 0;
    }

    if (shader == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader.");
    }

    return shader;
}

/**
 * Checks if we've had an error inside of OpenGL ES, and if so what that error is.
 *
 * @param func
 */
private static void checkGLError(String func) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e(TAG, func + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(func + ": glError " + error);
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the view to our CardboardView and initializes the transformation matrices we will use
 * to render our scene.
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cardboardView = (CardboardView) findViewById(R.id.cardboard_view);
    cardboardView.setRenderer(this);
    setCardboardView(cardboardView);

    mCamera = new float[16];
    mView = new float[16];
    mOverlayView = (CardboardOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
    //mOverlayView.show3DToast("Pull the magnet when you find an object.");
}

@Override
public void onRendererShutdown() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRendererShutdown");
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged");
}

/**
 * Creates the buffers we use to store information about the 3D world. OpenGL doesn't use Java
 * arrays, but rather needs data in a format it can understand. Hence we use ByteBuffers.
 *
 * @param config The EGL configuration used when creating the surface.
 */
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig config) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated");
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.5f); // Dark background so text shows up well

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareVertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureVertices.length * 4);
    bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureVerticesBuffer = bb2.asFloatBuffer();
    textureVerticesBuffer.put(textureVertices);
    textureVerticesBuffer.position(0);

    int vertexShader = loadGLShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = loadGLShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    texture = createTexture();
    startCamera(texture);
}

/**
 * Prepares OpenGL ES before we draw a frame.
 *
 * @param headTransform The head transformation in the new frame.
 */
@Override
public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
    float[] mtx = new float[16];
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    surface.updateTexImage();
    surface.getTransformMatrix(mtx);
}

@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture arg0) {
    this.cardboardView.requestRender();
}

/**
 * Draws a frame for an eye. The transformation for that eye (from the camera) is passed in as
 * a parameter.
 *
 * @param transform The transformations to apply to render this eye.
 */
@Override
public void onDrawEye(EyeTransform transform) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture);


    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "position");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);


    mTextureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "inputTextureCoordinate");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, vertexStride, textureVerticesBuffer);

    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "s_texture");


    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);


    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordHandle);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mView, 0, transform.getEyeView(), 0, mCamera, 0);

}

@Override
public void onFinishFrame(Viewport viewport) {
}

@Override
public void onCardboardTrigger() {

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ui_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView
    android:id="@+id/cardboard_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<com.oculab.mehmettaha.vrcamera.CardboardOverlayView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hence how can I handle this problem. I' ve tried to change camera resolution, but it didn' t work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the camera preview size. Its expecting to be at or near full screen size but you're trying to make it half the width with the same height. After trying this I found the aspect much improved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19592492/922339. It set the optimal preview size to 352 by 288 on my Nexus 5

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense! I' ll try as soon as possible. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the camera views to fill the screen, and don't mind if the preview is cropped on left and right. So, when you set the texture coordinates (`textureVeryices`), use left=0.25 and right=0.75.