# Capture a certain part on a full screen camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

Lets say this picture below is a full screen custom camera, how could I capture a square photo from the inside of that red square?

[image]

I chose this approach on custom camera to avoid [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121963/how-can-i-set-camera-preview-size-to-squared-aspect-ratio-in-a-squared-surfacevi) kind of problem which results to a squashed preview for square camera. After the process the output should be like this :

[image]

I just want to try the solution that Instagram used to prevent that squashed-image-from-square-camera issue, I read it from the accepted answer of @xramos from [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121963/how-can-i-set-camera-preview-size-to-squared-aspect-ratio-in-a-squared-surfacevi) also.

Here's what he said :

[image]

Please help me fellow prgrammers :) Thank you and have a good day :D